# Template path doesnt exist but still sees

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

Using Magento, I have a template path as follows:

```
frontend/base/default/template/epicor_comm/checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml
```

going through the source i located the epicor_comm folder and changed its name to something different for now just so it doesnt use this path anymore and defaults.  However this sint the case the path hints stays the same.

I cleared the caching and disabled it in the magento admin area, but cant seem to figure out why the path hint can still see this file even though the path shouldnt exist anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For file fallback, you need to put file with same name in your desired package and theme folder.

For example in `frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/template/epicor_comm/checkout/cart/` and put file with `sidebar.phtml` name

So now it will use this theme's file instead of base file.